# Issues Validating login using Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, validation

[Using POST it remains empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GMld.png), with GET the array isn't empty but the even the CORRECT login details don't work. Creating a login area in a site using codeigniter but the password isn't validating properly or at all. I've researched but I'm not sure why the problem persists. It just says every password is wrong. Also the password isn't getting fetched with POST but works with GET. This is the view area:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION)) {
                        echo $this->session->flashdata('flash_data');
                        } ?>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    <form action="<?php echo base_url('Login/index'); ?>" method="POST">

                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="user_password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me

                                    </label>
                                </div>
```

Then the controller:

```
 $data = array();

        print_r($_POST);

        if($_POST){
                $result=$this->User->validate($_POST);

                //print_r($result);

                if(!empty($result)){
                    $data=[
                    'id'=> $result[0]['id'], 
                    'username'=>$result[0]['username']
                    ];

                    //print_r($data);

                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect(base_url('dashboard/index'));
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Username or password is incorrect!');
                    redirect(base_url('login/index'));
                }
        }   

        $page='login';
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php')){
                    show_404();
        }
        $this->load->view($page);

     }
```

and model:

```
function validate($data){
    $this->db->select('id, username');
    //$this->db->from('login');
    $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
    $this->db->where('user_password', md5($data['user_password']));
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $res = $this->db->get('login')->result_array(); 

    return $res;

    //$query=$this->db->get();
  }

  function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }
```

Comment: Check if $data['username'] is the right way to access your post data. Try printing it. Better to send it as $this->input->post()

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code. Try to run the project in `Incognito Window`. I try the exact code in my project and its working fine.

Comment: on `print_r($result)` in controller, what is the result you are getiing?

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();

        print_r($_POST);

        if($_POST){
                $result=$this->User->validate($this->input->post());

                //print_r($result);

                if(!empty($result)){
                    $data=[
                    'id'=> $result[0]['id'], 
                    'username'=>$result[0]['username']
                    ];

                    //print_r($data);

                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect(base_url('dashboard/index'));
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Username or password is incorrect!');
                    redirect(base_url('login/index'));
                }
        }   

        $page='login';
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php')){
                    show_404();
        }
        $this->load->view($page);

     }
```

Comment: It still doesn't get the values using POST.

Comment: It just leaves the array empty. When I take out the comment ($this->db->from('login')) in the model it gets it but that screws up the querry.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to close **form** tag in views page. Then check, your form data are post to controller.

why you comment `$this->db->from('login')` in model. Please used this code in model for validate user login data in database.

```
function validate($data){

    $this->db->select('id, username');
    $this->db->from('login');
    $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
    $this->db->where('user_password', md5($data['user_password']));
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $res = $this->db->get(); 

    if($res->num_rows()){
       return $res->result_array();
    }else{
      return;
    }

  }
```

Comment: It is similar to call table name in `get()`

Comment: When i take the comment out. It becomes select id, username from login.login where ...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->input->post()
```

insted of

```
$_POST
```

Also if you have used salt, make sure to md5 password with salt.

```
md5($this->config['salt'].$data['user_password'])
```